# Why isn't my code copying files to another directory?

Tags: java, android, file, copy, move

Why are my codes not working its way copy a file from a directory to another after being initialized? Where it does not seems to even loop into the copyFile class method? Is it because i have not given it time to copy/transfer the file or have i done something wrong in my codes?

I'm rather new in android/programming can someone help?

Alertdialog onClick function to call upon the copyFile method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write to the archive directory itself, instead of to a new file inside that directory.

Comment: Inside `copyFile`, after you ensure that `destFile` points to a directory that actually exists, I think it may be enough to create a File that points to the actual output file desired: `destFile = new File(destFile, sourceFile.getName());`

Comment: @Ted Hopp i have updated my code above is it this way? Sorry if i'm wrong i'm rather new in android/java..

Comment: @Ted Hopp or i need the progress bar during transfer because when i return to the folder i don't seems to see the file? After after a while it reappear...

Comment: @Vivian - Your updated code creates the File object pointing to the desired file, but you appear to have deleted all the code that does the transfer! I had meant that after ensuring that the destination directory exists, you should redefine `destFile` to point to a new file _and then proceed with the rest of the method as it was_.

Comment: @Vivian - As to the progress bar not appearing, you will need to move the entire file copying process to an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to allow the UI to continue operating.

Comment: @Ted Hopp which means i have create a new java file to handle AsyncTask or it still stays at the same java file?

Comment: @Ted Hopp for my case how should i use AsyncTask to update my progress bar, i saw a similar example here but i don't know how to implement it in my own context? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog can you help me with this?

Comment: @Vivian - it's a little hard to answer an entirely new question using comments. It would be best if you start a new question, posting the code you have now and explaining where you need help.

Comment: @Ted Hopp i've try it out for the AsyncTask but it happen to arouse another problem for not updating my listview entry content whyis it so? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060982/why-is-the-content-of-my-listview-entries-not-updated-after-the-transfer-of-file