# Why is the content of my listview entries not updated after the file transfer is completed?

Tags: java, android, listview

Why is it that after copying the file to the directory the `listview` is not updated with newer content which reside in that directory? Only when I exit the `listview` and reenter the view will it be refreshed?

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Copying of file function java file

Comment: perhaps try invalidate() on your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the newly copied files (VideoInfo objects) onto your ArchiveItems list, and then you can call listview.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the ListView, it seems you're not doing it (but there's too much code to look at maybe I've missed something)

or you can just reload the listview contents after your task has finished coping the new items (with loadVideoFiles() or whatever)

Comment: @ShadowCloud i don't quite get your explanation?

Comment: @Vivian I think ShadowCloud meant that in your AsyncTask's `onPostExecute` method, you should arrange for `getVideoFiles` to be called. (This is the simplest, but not the most efficient, way to update your list.)

Comment: @Ted Hopp but the problem here is such that both the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method and getVideoFiles are different activities? How should i solve this problem?

Comment: @Ted Hopp i could not be calling a new intent activity because when i press the back button it returns to the previous Archive activity view with the content still remain not updated?

Comment: @Vivian - Different activities or different files? If it's a different activity, then in `ArchiveActivity`, you can override `onResume` to call `getVideoFiles` when it comes back to the foreground after the other activity finishes. If it's just different compilation units, write a call-back method (or make `getVideoFiles` something other than `private`).

Comment: @Ted Hopp Thanks for your sound advice. Now it works.. :) But can you take a look at another of my question here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060567/how-to-enable-autoplay-of-video-in-sequences-upon-selection-in-a-listview